# Rolling On-Hand Remainder column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

`CONumber, LineNumber, PartNumber, OrderQty, ScheduleDate, OnHandQty` columns are a pure `SELECT` query with no transformations. I am trying to recreate the `RollingOnHand` column in SQL.

The rules are

1. If a part only has one row, report the real [`OnHandQty`]
2. If a part has multiple rows, the oldest order consumes its [`OrderQty`] from [`OnHandQty`]
3. The next oldest order pulls its [`OrderQty`] from the remaining [`OnHandQty`], repeat until final row of the matching part
4. The last row of a given part will display the remaining [`OnHandQty`]

Is this possible to accomplish in an SQL query?

| CONumber | LineNumber | PartNumber | OrderQty | ScheduleDate | OnHandQty | RollingOnHand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C02959 | 00002 | Part 01 | 102 | 2022-04-01 | 0 | 0 |
| C04017 | 00001 | Part 02 | 2007 | 2022-04-01 | 5099 | 5099 |
| C04107 | 00001 | Part 03 | 1 | 2022-03-09 | 0 | 0 |
| C04106 | 00001 | Part 04 | 1 | 2022-03-09 | 0 | 0 |
| C04108 | 00001 | Part 05 | 1 | 2022-03-09 | 0 | 0 |
| C03514 | 00002 | Part 06 | 250 | 2022-03-11 | 310 | 250 |
| C03514 | 00003 | Part 06 | 250 | 2022-03-18 | 310 | 60 |
| C03757 | 00001 | Part 06 | 250 | 2022-04-06 | 310 | 0 |
| C04225 | 00002 | Part 07 | 40 | 2022-03-31 | 53 | 53 |
| C03965 | 00002 | Part 08 | 24 | 2022-04-04 | 0 | 0 |
| C04034 | 00001 | Part 09 | 88 | 2022-03-18 | 128 | 128 |
| C04144 | 00002 | Part 10 | 22 | 2022-04-04 | 0 | 0 |
| C04141 | 00001 | Part 10 | 100 | 2022-04-04 | 0 | 0 |
| C03734 | 00003 | Part 11 | 116 | 2022-03-29 | 103 | 103 |
| C03379 | 00001 | Part 12 | 128 | 2022-03-07 | 19 | 19 |
| C03344 | 00003 | Part 13 | 40 | 2022-03-11 | 5 | 5 |
| C04058 | 00001 | Part 14 | 407 | 2022-03-25 | 0 | 0 |
| C03697 | 00002 | Part 15 | 436 | 2022-04-04 | 235 | 235 |
| C03689 | 00002 | Part 16 | 111 | 2022-03-16 | 87 | 87 |
| C03690 | 00001 | Part 16 | 250 | 2022-03-23 | 87 | 0 |
| C03690 | 00002 | Part 16 | 250 | 2022-04-06 | 87 | 0 |
| C03240 | 00004 | Part 17 | 3 | 2022-03-16 | 30 | 3 |
| C03725 | 00001 | Part 17 | 250 | 2022-03-16 | 30 | 27 |
| C03725 | 00002 | Part 17 | 250 | 2022-03-23 | 30 | 0 |
| C03726 | 00001 | Part 17 | 250 | 2022-04-01 | 30 | 0 |
| C03726 | 00002 | Part 17 | 250 | 2022-04-06 | 30 | 0 |
| C03596 | 00017 | Part 18 | 56 | 2022-04-06 | 344 | 344 |
| C03927 | 00001 | Part 19 | 600 | 2022-04-04 | 1800 | 600 |
| C03927 | 00002 | Part 19 | 1000 | 2022-04-06 | 1800 | 1200 |

Comment: Presumably you have a table "stock" or similar? Please post table definitions etc, preferably as DBfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this basically does what you need ([Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=563df0a21fbe291bc89f89ff522e11a9))

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT *, 
        AlreadyConsumed = SUM(OrderQty) OVER (PARTITION BY [PartNumber] ORDER BY  ScheduleDate ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),
        PrevLineNumber = LAG([LineNumber]) OVER (PARTITION BY [PartNumber] ORDER BY  ScheduleDate ASC),
        NextLineNumber = LEAD([LineNumber]) OVER (PARTITION BY [PartNumber] ORDER BY  ScheduleDate ASC)
FROM Demo
)
SELECT CONumber,
       LineNumber,
       PartNumber,
       OrderQty,
       ScheduleDate,
       OnHandQty,
       RollingOnHand = CASE
                         --If a part only has one row, report the real [OnHandQty]
                         WHEN PrevLineNumber IS NULL
                              AND NextLineNumber IS NULL THEN OnHandQty
                         --Not the last row and won't use all the remainder up
                         WHEN NextLineNumber IS NOT NULL AND Remainder > OrderQty THEN OrderQty
                         --otherwise use what's left
                         ELSE Remainder
                       END
FROM   T
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN AlreadyConsumed > OnHandQty THEN 0 ELSE OnHandQty - ISNULL(AlreadyConsumed,0) END) C(Remainder)
```

The

`SUM ... PARTITION BY [PartNumber] ... ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING` computes the cumulative OrderQty for all rows before  the current row (not including it)

The `LAG`/ `LEAD` results are used as indicators to determine whether we are in the first/last rows of a partition and special logic is needed.

I didn't quite follow the rationale behind the business logic so I may have made some invalid simplifications but it returns the desired results with the sample data and anyway the query should be easy to tweak if needed.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks so much.

I'm not a fan of the column either. I'm just trying to create an automated version of a coworker's report to save them some time every morning. 

There's a lot of new stuff in this query that I've never encountered as a self-taught SQL coder, so I'm excited to look them up piece by piece and maybe use them going forward with other projects.